# Assign custom roles with a function and Microsoft Graph in statci web apps

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to follow [Tutorial: Assign custom roles with a function and Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/assign-roles-microsoft-graph)

I have gone through each step carefully and configured all the setting properly.
But when I clikc `Login` I see following error in console

```
GET https://victorious-island-091e86f10.1.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad 404 (Not Found)
```

Looks like the static web page doesn't have access to `/.auth`

`staticwebapp.config.json` has

```
    "auth": {
        "rolesSource": "/api/GetRoles",
        "identityProviders": {
            "azureActiveDirectory": {
                "userDetailsClaim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                "registration": {
                    "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my tenant id>",
                    "clientIdSettingName": "AAD_CLIENT_ID",
                    "clientSecretSettingName": "AAD_CLIENT_SECRET"
                },
                "login": {
                    "loginParameters": [
                        "resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below points give an idea .
I followed the doc and tried to login, and

1. Got the404 not found error .
   Some times it maybe due to some whitespace or extra character like (dot.) after callback or somewhere in azure ad app redirect url
   example: https://kind-ground-0932d10.1.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback. (in my case)
2. Please make sure to add cliend id and secret name and value each, in the  Application settings section under configuration blade ,if it has to be used in staticwebapp.config.json

[image]

3. Also please make sure to grant consent to the graph permissions required .
   Make sure to tick the Id token in the authentication section.
   Delete cache and cookies .Then go to website https://kind-ground-0932d10.1.azurestaticapps.net/  and try to login

---

**Other workarounds:**

Try if it works with v2 endpoint  and by removing clientsecretsettingname.We need to erase userDetailsClaim,if we use v2 endpoint: [Reference](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/413#issuecomment-840787214)

```
"auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "azureActiveDirectory": {
        "registration": {
          "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/v2.0",
          "clientIdSettingName": "STATICWEBCLIENTID"
        }
```

Check the json file for routes if they are set to  return 404 .

```
{
  "route": "/.auth/login/aad",
  "statusCode": 404
}
```

Or

Try to create [routing rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization?tabs=invitations#login) to redirect to a aad route

[example-configuration-file- Azure Static Web Apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#example-configuration-file)

For Example ,routes in staticwebapp.config.json :

```
"routes": [
     {
       "route": "/login",
       "rewrite": "/.auth/login/aad"
     },
     {
       "route": "/api/*",
       "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
     },
    {
       "route": "/admin*",
       "allowedRoles": ["administrator"]
    }
...
]
```

Also please check this [blog](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/azure-how-to-configure-fallback-routes-for-react-static-web-apps-ac3bc33c0088#:%7E:text=Placing%20routes.json%20(depreciated))

> Note: Customizing authentication and assigning roles using a function
> require the Standard Hosting plan.

**References:**

1. [Azure Static website react.js getting 404 in the browser but
   returning the correct content on a path - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/313157/azure-static-website-reactjs-getting-404-in-the-br.html)
2. [Authentication and authorization for Azure Static Web Apps |
   Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization?tabs=invitations)